# Python Socket recvfrom() overtime?

Tags: python, sockets, recv

I have a Thread that has a socket that waits for message using:

```
message, addr = s.recvfrom(268)
```

Is there to have an exception handler that after a certain time, it will time out and do something else?

For reference I am implementing a token ring in python using sockets and threads.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call [settimeout](http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html#socket.socket.settimeout). You can catch `socket.error` to detect timeouts.

Comment: I added the except timeout but after the time that passes which I set, I receive an error saying: AttributeError: '_socketobject' object has no attribute 'timeout'. I looked around and some other people had problems but theirs involved with Python being less up to date.

Comment: hm, I fixed it by just saying except, It might cause problems if I require any other exception to be set up, what would be a correct exception call for timeout?